# is index to be used at the expressions?

Tags: sql, indexing

-- INDEX 1
create index on post (owner_id, likes_count)

-- QUERY 1
select * from post where owner_id = ?

---

-- INDEX 2
create index on post (owner_id)
create index on post (likes_count)

-- QUERY 2
select * from post where owner_id = ? AND likes_count = ?

---

I think index is used in both, am I right?

Comment: The indexes may or may not be used depending on how the query optimiser decides how to execute the query

Comment: What's the database? Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in the first scenario: the index is likely to be chosen by the optimizer. No in the second scennario: where only one of the two indexes will get used but not both.